# Excel: Assign multiple ids to a other ids.

Tags: excel

im stuck with this problem: I want to pair a multiple records with same id from sheet1 to records from sheet2. All these records from subgroup of same ids should be pasted to the last row in finalsheet (in one cell)

My progress:
Col C
=COUNTIF(A:A;A2)   To get number of all records with same id.
Col D
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2;A2)  To get first record of group of ids.

Ill filter all records started with 1.
Col E
On the next column ill do a =CELL("address";D2) - To get an address of cell with one
Col F
Next column  =ROW(E2)+C2-1 to get a position of last cell with same id.
Row G
=CONCATENATE("$D$";F3) to get a proper syntax of last cell with same id.

Now ive got a range of these subgroups.
So its possible to do a =CONCATENATE(first cell of subgroup:last cell of subgroup) ?

Thanks for help and sry for my english :d

```
sheet1
id  status
131 car - bad engine
131 bike - ok
131 cyclo - ok
132 car - high engine temperature
132 bike - ok 
133 car - ok
133 bike -ok
133 cyclo - ok 

sheet2
131 1.1.2011
132 6.1.2011
133 8.1.2011


resultsheet
131 1.1.2011   car - bad engine
               bike - ok
               cyclo - ok
132 6.1.2011   car - high engine temperature
               bike - ok
133 8.1.2011   car - ok
               bike -ok
               cyclo - ok
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not read your question(!) but looking at your example it seems a lookup of date (?) into sheet1 from sheet2 based on id and a PivotTable in Tabular form with all three columns as ROWS and no subtotals would suit nicely.